# How can I properly load an image with Express's static middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm kind of new to express, in my server:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'includes')));
```

In my client javascript i'm simply giving the url:

```
var img = $("<img />").attr('src', 'http://localhost:3000/includes/images/img.png');
$(".logo-container").append(img);
```

but still getting a 404

Comment: Does your image exist within a directory called `images`?

Comment: yes indeed, i tried with another image in this folder also, but still

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the example from [`express.static` documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use),

> Serve static content for the app from the `public` directory in the application directory:
>
> ```
> // GET /style.css etc
> app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
> ```

As the example shows,

1. when you mount the `static` middleware without any explicit path, it will be mounted in the root and
2. the directory you pass to `express.static` is the location in the server, not a part of the URL.

So, you should access the image without `/includes` like this

```
var img = $("<img />").attr('src', 'http://localhost:3000/images/img.png');
$(".logo-container").append(img);
```

Or if you want to access it with `includes`, you need to change the registration, like this

```
app.use('/includes', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'includes')));
```

Comment: Now i understand, thank you. by the way, it also worked that way without the root /:     app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));